# Efficiently query tables when one has many references

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: class and instructors.

```
class
id: int
title: varchar(45)

instructor
id: int
class_id: int
name: varchar(45)
```

Let's say there are two instructors that are associated with one class:

```
INSERT INTO `class` VALUES(1, 'Class Number 1');
INSERT INTO `instructor` VALUES (1, 1, 'John Smith');
INSERT INTO `instructor` VALUES (2, 1, 'Jane Smith');
```

How do I go about querying a list of classes with instructor names? There were two ways I thought about querying and was hoping for a more efficient method.

1. Query once every class

   SELECT * FROM `class`;
   SELECT * FROM `instructor` WHERE class_id=?;
2. Query them together with the same class in multiple rows

   SELECT * FROM `class` c, `instructor` i, WHERE `c`.`id` = `i`.`class_id` GROUP BY `c`.`id`;

What I was hoping for way an output of the class list with instructors separated by a comma.

Comment: There are platform-specific approaches to this; can you tell us what database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function. Be aware of [these notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Of your two methods in most cases the latter one is faster as having many queries costs time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.title, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name) 
FROM class c, instructor i
WHERE c.id = i.class_id GROUP BY c.id;
```